# После доставания JSONObject из json пропадает поле id. Java. vk api

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api

Изначально json приходит в виде (в списке items есть поле id равное 4 у  первого элемента !!!):

```
{"response":{"count":2,"items":[{"id":4,"from_id":-183957790,"owner_id":-183957790,.....
```

Потом я достаю JSONObject response

```
JSONObject inputJSON = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(resultJson);
JSONObject response = (JSONObject) inputJSON.get("response");
```

В итоге я получаю такой json (Поле id уже нету !!!):

```
{"count":2,"items":[{"date":1561831569,"from_id":-183957790,"comments":{"count":2,....
```

Как это можно исправить ? (Использую json-simple)

Comment: А у вас что-то еще меняется? потому что у вас изначальная строка `"id":4,"from_id":-183957790,"owner_id":-183957790` , а в новой уже есть `"date":1561831569  , "comments"` а `owner_id` исчез

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"response\":{\"count\":2,\"items\":[{\"id\":4,\"from_id\":-183957790,\"owner_id\":-183957790}]}}";
    parseCurrentWeatherJson(json);
}

public static void parseCurrentWeatherJson(String resultJson) {
    try {           
        JSONObject response = (JSONObject) ((JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(resultJson)).get("response");
        System.out.println(response);
        JSONArray weatherArray = (JSONArray) response.get("items");            
        JSONObject weatherData = (JSONObject) weatherArray.get(0);
        System.out.println(weatherData.keySet()); // you can see all objects keys 
        System.out.println(weatherData.get("owner_id"));//get value of 'owner_id' for example

    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Уже отвечал и еще раз отвечаю...
Вот код, вот результат выполнения:

{"count":2,"items":[{"from_id":-183957790,"owner_id":-183957790,"id":4}]}

[from_id, owner_id, id]

-183957790

В первой строке последним светится айдишник.

Так что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за беспокойство. 
Я так понимаю порядок полей просто изменился ?

Comment: порядок полей для джейсона не гарантирован и для того, чтобы распарсить джейсон, это тоже не имет никакого значения